# Steps of troubleshooting in messaging extensions

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have the following problem and need your help:
I've been developing a messaging extension for a few weeks that can be used to process messages. The corresponding code is on my own web server and I have created an app including app channels registration and everything that goes with it.
Since yesterday noon the forwarding of the click event to "OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync" does not work anymore. Via the debugger I can see that both the constructor of my messaging extension (inherits from TeamsActivityHandler) and the bot controller (constructor and action PostAsync()) are called. Unfortunately the method "OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync" is not called anymore.
In the browser I see the error message "Failed to send message to agent, error code 1008" and the messaging extension cannot be reached.

What options do I have to troubleshoot this? Until yesterday morning the code was running without problems and I did not make any changes. Therefore I don't think that it is because of my web service. I suspect it has something to do with permissions between messaging extension and bot and bot channels registration.

Comment: Update: now everything is running normally again. What happened? I have not changed anything on my web service, permissions, app, etc. I only have installed the windows updates on the web server and restarted it. 
Is it possible that this was the reason? 

However, I still wonder what troubleshooting steps I could have taken.

Comment: Hi @Anne, Since you did not change any code and just restarted the web server, it may have been some issue with network or web server. Also if you have implemented any telemetry for your web service you can check there also.